# How do I add an Approver to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-services

I am still new to SharePoint and am learning so much, but have came in to a few hic-ups and here is one.

I want to add an approver to SharePoint 2010 who has FULL CONTROL. My manager requested that I find out where the approval request are going and redirect them to him. (I have no idea where or how to find this out). Is this possible to do on the Central Administration or must I go into each site/subsite and set him to be the approver this way? Googled and the site was showing me how to approve workflows or how to create approvals, my other resources didn't give much help either. So far I had gone into a few individual sites and set my manager and I up as approvers with full control, but am uncertain if this is the correct procedure or if there is a better way to do this. For example, have the lower levels inherit from the higher level - set security at the highest level and cascade to the child levels.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the approver at Web Application Level:[Manage permissions for a Web application (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607719.aspx). You need to give your manager there the approval permission:
On site level you can do it this way:[Configure custom permissions (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx#section2)

So, you can configure the permissions per site, or per web application. Permissions on securable objects within a site are inherited from the parent object by default. See for information about site permissions and inherantance here:[Plan site permissions (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262778.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I believe I go this now. I went to the main Portal and edited permissions and made my manager and I the main approvers. So hopefully this is taken care of now. Thank You for your help. :)